# using Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

if i create a new instance of JdbcTemplate like so;

JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());

by passing the datasource as a param (the datasource retrieves a connection from server connection pool) am i required to close the connection when im finished with it?

In other words, if i have a pool of connections will the previous code cause my application to create a new connection each time a request executes the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. That's the whole deal. Use the JdbcTemplate and it will manage the ressources (Connection, PreparedStatement, ResultSet). It is an implementation of the [template method design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

[Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html):

> It simplifies the use of JDBC and helps to avoid common errors. It
>   executes core JDBC workflow, leaving
>   application code to provide SQL and
>   extract results.

Answer (score 0):

What I did, was to extend the JdbcTemplate and override the execute method to use the connection pool (a particular case).

Comment: I don't know the details of your particular case, but in general, [`JdbcTemplate` will be injected with a `DataSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate-idioms) which is an instance of the class `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` and thus already implements connection pooling.

Comment: In my case the connections are pooled per user